# Analogous of Power of Point in Euclidean Geometry in high dimension

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, circles

While playing around with dot product in 2D, I realized it's [scalar projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_projection) behavior is directly related to [power of point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point) in Euclidean Geometry.

I am wondering if there is any notion similar to power of point in higher dimension or other branches of geometry.

Answer (score 0):

The power of a point with respect to a circle in a plane is easily generalized to spheres in 3D space, and similarly for higher dimensions. The notions of distance and radius still apply.